# Посчитать вырученную сумму от продаж в SQL

Tags: sql

Закуплены цветы, часть из них позже продана. Сколько заработано с уже проданных цветов за 2019 год? 
Есть 3 таблицы с данными (некоторые атрибуты убрал, так как полагаю, они не нужны):

Товар (Номер_товара, Себестоимость)
Составляет (Номер_товара, Номер_заказа, Количество, Сумма(то есть сколько всего заплачено за все количество))
Заказ (Номер_заказа, Дата)

Comment: А как сами пытались решать? Что не получается? Алгоритм может быть таким: Отбираете номера заказов по нужным датам, присоединяете к результату таблицу "составляет" по номеру заказа и таблицу Товаров по по номеру товара. И по полученной выборке посчитать сумму( Сумма-себестоимость* кол-во)...

Comment: Ответ я нашел тут, помогло https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256813/select-sum-from-select-select
Проблема решена!

Answer (score -2):

```
select
    sum(b.kaina - b.kiekis*a.kaina) as profit
from preke as a
    inner join sudaro as b on a.prekesnr = b.prekesnr
    inner join uzsakymas as c on b.uzsakymonr = c.uzsakymonr
```